# struts2 if greater than/less than equal etc

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tags, logic

I get the feeling this is a bad idea in struts2:

```
<s:if test="%{#someVar >= 60}">Hello</s:if>
```

Is this actually legal? If not what is a better way to check some value within the JSP?

Thanks

Comment: Is it the "greater-than", angley bracket that you don't like? If so, you can use `gte` in place of `>=` in OGNL - http://commons.apache.org/ognl/language-guide.html

Comment: I had some issues with the code, and wondered if this should work as expected on a var that is numeric?

Comment: I see the OGNL syntax allows it but actually this is not valid XML is it?

Answer (score 0):

The angle bracket i.e `>` is legal inside the `if` struts tag. From the [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html) shared by @rees, under the section **Appendix: OGNL Language Reference > Operators**, you can see this example:

> e1 >= e2, e1 gte e2
> Greater than or equals comparison

In your case:

```
<s:if test="%{#someVar gte 60}">Hello</s:if>
```

and you don't need the `%{}`, as the `#` sign is already telling Struts to go and find the *someVar* on the `ActionContext`. Better still, you don't need the `#` sign, if *someVar* is on the `Value Stack`, i.e declared as a property in your Action class with getter and setter.

This does not work though:
<s:if test="%{#someVar <s>***&gte;***</s> 60}">Hello</s:if>